# How do I remove multiple random characters from a string in python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, random, python-3.8

I have come up with the following code but unfortunately its only removing 1 character from my string.

```py
import random
string = 'HelloWorld!'
def remove_random_character(phrase):
        character_number = random.randint(0, len(phrase))
        remover = f'{phrase[:character_number - 1]}_{phrase[character_number:]}'
        for _ in range(8):
            sliced_phrase = remover
        print(sliced_phrase)
remove_random_character(string)
```

I thought that the for loop will take care of this but unfortunately it did not. but every time it loops it just refreshes the `sliced_phrase` variable. but I do not know how to store the last version of the loop, for that to be edited. So how can I can I remove multiple random characters from a string?

Comment: What is expected string?

Comment: You function doesn't return any value. Insert a `return sliced_phrase` after/instead of the print statement. Then call the function like this: `result = remove_random_character(string)`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over every letter in your string and decide do you need to remove it:

```
import random
string = 'HelloWorld!'
output = ''.join([s for s in string if random.random() < 0.7])
```

Test:

```
Heloold!
elloWld!
loWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def remove_random_char(string):
    char_index_to_remove = random.randint(0, len(string)-1)
    string = string.replace(string[char_index_to_remove], '', 1)

    return string

string = 'HelloWorld!'
times_to_iterate = 4 
for i in range(times_to_iterate):
    string = remove_random_char(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```py
import random
def remove_random_character(phrase, n_remove):
    for num in random.sample(range(0, len(phrase)), n_remove):
        phrase = phrase[:num] + '_' + phrase[num + 1:]
    return phrase
```

Then to remove, say, 3 random characters:

```py
string = 'HelloWorld!'
new_phrase = remove_random_character(string, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
phrase = 'HelloWorld!'
num_of_missing_chars = 4
def random_char_remover(string: str, num_missing_char: int):
    def index_remover(string: str):
        char_index_to_remove = random.randint(0, len(string)-1)
        string = string.replace(string[char_index_to_remove], '_', 1)
        return string

    for i in range(num_missing_char):
        string = index_remover(string)
    print(string)
random_char_remover(phrase, num_of_missing_chars)
```

Thanks guys this is what I got finally after reviewing all your answers and using a bit of all of them. it may be a little simplified from my end but I only work with code that I can understand.
:)